# strange error on my android set frame application

Tags: android, image, image-processing, bitmap, frame

i create an application that set a frame to a image bitmap... but when the process give a result, i don't know, why the result bitmap are also saved to my original bitmap variabel, this is my code :

main code :

```
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.frame);
    tampilFrame = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivframe);
    oribmp = temporary.getBitmap();
            temp = oribmp;
    tampilFrame.setImageBitmap(temp);
    frame00 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.frs00);
    frame00.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            frame = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fr00));
            frame = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(frame, 800, 800, false);
            new backtask().execute();
        }
    });
    frame01 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.frs01);
    frame01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            frame = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fr01));
            frame = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(frame, 800, 800, false);
            new backtask().execute();
        }
    });
    frame02 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.frs02);
    frame02.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            frame = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fr02));
            frame = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(frame, 800, 800, false);
            new backtask().execute();
        }
    });
    frame03 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.frs03);
    frame03.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            frame = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fr03));
            frame = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(frame, 800, 800, false);
            new backtask().execute();
        }
    });
}
```

}

the variabel frame00, frame01, frame02 are ImageView that I set as a Button. When the user click the frame image, it will load an image from drawable and stored in a variabel named "frame" and also call a asyncTask named "backtask".

this is the "backtask" code

```
public class backtask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog prog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        prog =  ProgressDialog.show(FrameActivity.this, "", "Progress...");     
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        temp = setFrame(oribmp);
        Log.i("temp", "widht : "+String.valueOf(temp.getWidth())+" Height : "+String.valueOf(temp.getHeight()));
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void res){
        super.onPostExecute(res);
        tampilFrame.setImageBitmap(temp);
        prog.dismiss();
        Log.i("setFrame", "Complete");
    }
}
```

this backtask code i used to make a loading progress when the application runs the "setFrame()" code. and this is my "setFrame" code :

```
public Bitmap setFrame(Bitmap bit){
    for (int i=0;i<frame.getWidth();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<frame.getHeight();j++){
            if (Color.alpha(frame.getPixel(i, j))!=0){
                bit.setPixel(i, j, frame.getPixel(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
    frame.recycle();
    return bit;
}
```

the oribmp is a variabel that containt original bitmap get from class temporary.getBitmap()
when the "temp = setFrame(oribmp);" finish, the ori bmp has also changes same as the temp.
when i checked to class temporary, the bitmap variabel that contain original bitmap on the temporary class also changes to the result of the setFrame...

this is the code pf temporary class

```
public class temporary {
private static Bitmap Mbmp;

public static Bitmap getBitmap () {
    return Mbmp;
}

public static void setBitmap(Bitmap oribimp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Mbmp = oribimp;
    Log.i("editor", "simpen bitmap");
}
```

}

temporary class is a class that i used to send the bitmap value to another activity in my application.. this is what the FrameActivity looks like on the run..

strart activity
[image: this is the look of FrameActivity when its first start, the original bitmap is that gecko]this is the look of FrameActivity when its first start, the original bitmap is that gecko

set frame 1
[image: this is the looks when set the first frame]this is the looks when set the first frame

set frame 2
[image: this is the looks when set the second frame, cause the oribmp has the same value like the result of the first seFrame, on the second setFrame they looks like pile up]
this is the looks when set the second frame, cause the oribmp has the same value like the result of the first seFrame, on the second setFrame they looks like pile up

im sory if my question is too long, maybe anyone can give me solution :D

Comment: I took one look at your code and usually I decide to just move on to the next question, but I felt like letting you know why I didn't read your question, and maybe why others won't. Your code looks horrible. I know that's harsh, but it's extremely unreadable to the point where I don't want to bother. Please take some time to format your code better, name variables appropriately, move duplicate code into a method, add a line break every now and then. Just make it readable. I'm not trying to be rude, but it will help you get responses to your questions.

Comment: tank you @JasonRobinson i had edit my question and split the code and explain it,,, maybe its can be useful.. :(

Comment: Sorry I was so harsh. I do admire that you did take the time to provide pictures and a thought out question, which automatically makes you better than 90% of other SO users.